# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await

Hi I have a function that returns a value from shared preferences, but initially it returns null/undefined is that because of the promise or the data reuturned from the shared preferences as initially there will not be anything in it.

```
export function getSharedPreferenceValue( key ) {
    SInfo.getItem(key, {
        sharedPreferencesName: sharedPreferenceName,
                keychainService: keyChainServiceName}).then(value => {
                    consoleLog('getSharedPreferenceValue - ' + key + ' - ' + value) //value 1
                    if( typeof value === 'undefined'){
                        return 'true';
                    }else{
                        return value;                    
                    }                    
                });
}
```

and using it like this

```
   whereShoulINavigateTo = async () => {
        const returned = await getSharedPreferenceValue( globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH).then ((isFirstLaunch) => {
            consoleLog('isFirstLaunch - ' + isFirstLaunch); 
            consoleLog('isFirstLaunch - ' + typeof isFirstLaunch); 
            //do something based on the value
        });
    }
```

Error is

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Where am i going wrong here

Comment: `getSharedPreferenceValue` doesn't return anythign

Comment: Should I be returning SINfo as well? something like `export function getSharedPreferenceValue( key ) {
    return SInfo.getItem(key, {`

Comment: @BRDroid yes, that is exactly what tou should do. `SInfo` seems to be a promise so if you return it you can call `.then` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a promise:

```
export function getSharedPreferenceValue(key) {
    dataObj = {
        sharedPreferenceName: sharedPreferenceName,
        keychainService: keyChainServiceName
    };

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        SInfo.getItem(key, dataObj).then(value => {
            console.log(`{key} {value}`);
            if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
                res('true');
            } else {
                rej(value)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then modify the second function accordingly.

```
whereShoulINavigateTo = async () => {
    getSharedPreferenceValue(globals.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY_FIRST_LAUNCH).then((isFirstLaunch) => {
        console.log(`{isFirstLaunch}`);
    }).catch((value) => {
        console.log('Failed');
    });
}
```